# How do I average time between to dates in Mongoose js?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, aggregate

I'm trying to query my mLab database and get the average time between two dates. I'm matching the data by name and between two dates (trying to get data within a day). There is data in the DB that i within the dates I'm providing but I'm getting undefined back. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
var dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  start: Date,
  end: Date,
  key: String
});
module.exports.GetAverageDataWithinRange = function(name, dates, callback) {
  Data.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      name: name,
      start: {
        $gte: dates.startDate,
        $lt: dates.endDate + 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      average: {
        $avg: {
          $subtract: [{
            $millisecond: "$end"
          }, {
            $millisecond: "$start"
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  }], function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      callback(results);
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: One way may be to use moment to convert the dates to a number (unix) and average using that format?

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/

Comment: I'm already doing that by using the date aggregate function $milliseconds right? @TaylorAckley